# ¿Cómo formateo un numero de 4 dígitos a tres dígitos y un decimal en php?

Tags: php, decimal

Tengo un numero, ejemplo 1226 y lo quiero convertir en 122.6 ¿se podría hacer eso?

Ya que e estado intentando pero no logro hacerlo.

El código que estoy utilizando es este:

```
$num = 1999;
echo number_format($num, 2, ",", "");
```

Pero lo que me devuelve es

> 1999,00

Espero que me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: Divide el numero entre 10, `echo $num / 10;`. ;)